# Dataframe group by several columns

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe like this

```
Quarter | Year | ID | Performance
Q1         2018   13   40
Q2         2019   37   60
.....
```

I would like to group the data not by a single column but I would like to have it grouped by year + quarter, so that I get sth like:

```
Q1 2019
ID | Performance

Q2 2019
ID | Performance
```

But when I use

```
df.groupby("Quarter").groupby("Year")
```

I get an error message that groupby cant be accessed for DataFrameGroupBy objects.

Answer (score 0):

try like these

```
df.groupby(["Year", "Quarter"])
```

also call aggregate function as follows

```
df.groupby(['Year', 'Quarter']).agg({'ID' : 'first', 'Performance':'mean'})
```

Comment: I get this output <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0000020A2C3564C8>. In retrospect maybe groupby was not the right approach. I should look how I can simply filter for two values in different columns.

Comment: We should do aggregation on the groupby objects. Please see the edited code for your reference.